# Capturing clicks even when stopPropagation has been called (ie by 3rd party code)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I want to detect any click that happens on a page (to close a custom context menu).  I'm using jQuery and trying to do

```
$(document).click(function(){ ...close my context menu ... });
```

However, I'm using some code that calls evt.stopPropagation() in the click handlers for certain elements on the page, and those clicks aren't making it up to my top-level handler.  Is there any way of capturing those clicks?  Can be jQuery or not jQuery, as long as it works cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the legacy code handles the click during the bubbling phase, you could handle the click in the capturing phase. Try:

```
element1.addEventListener('click', doSomethingFunction, true);
```

It's all explained very nicely here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Do you know how cross browser that is, though?  I recall seeing something about IE not working with it... wasn't able to find a straight answer when I google.d

Comment: You're right, you would have to use [setCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to cover IE. It's always IE :-/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an invisible div to your page, and then adding "showing" it, (not really because its invisible), when your menu is up. You could then attach an event listener to the invisible div that closes the popup and hides the div.

Comment: cool idea, although ideally I'd like users to be able to, with a single click, close the menu and interact with something else on the page, whereas I think this solution makes it two clicks.  but not a bad fallback...